# stripe: set void status to invoice

Tags: python, stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe on Python and I have the following situation:

1) Some user has X subscription to plan P1

2) That user wants to update X to plan P2 (which is more expensive)

3) In order to avoid fraud against us, I try to charge the user's source instantly by creating an invoice programatically and then using the .pay() function to do so.

4) My problem is: if the card is declined, I want to rollback all changes performed on my backend and on Stripe, thus I want to void that invoice because otherwise Stripe will attempt to charge the source again in a few days.

In this scenario, when I try to call the void_invoice() function that belongs to Invoice object, I got this error:

`AttributeError: void_invoice`

All the functions that I'm trying to use are on Stripe's api reference doc, and the invoice is in Status open (which means that it is finished) because of the previous call to pay().

https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/void

Comment: Do you mind sharing your full code on you were voiding the invoice?

Comment: I find out the solution, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was related to the old version installed.

I was on 1.X and thus install 2.X and everything works fine.